# if else statements in excel to count blank spaces in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup, hyperion

Good afternoon,

I was wondering if there is a way to count the number of blank spaces in a cell and return that value using a combination of vlookups, if else statements, and possible the len function? For example, the reports that are generated Generate values like this:

"TopLocation"
"     SubLocation" 
"          SubSubLocation"

My goal is to be able to automate some of these reports, but I feel like I'm missing one or more pieces to the puzzle.

Thank you.

Comment: I added an answer for what I think you're trying to do.  Your question would be much improved if you added the expected output along with the input (assuming those three in the middle are inputs).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a blank only refers to a simple space, , you can get this with a quick formula that takes the difference of the original length and the length after removing spaces.

**Formula** in B1 with data in A1, copied down to end of data

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", ""))
```

**Picture**

[image: picture of results]

**Data** in case you don't believe the image, where space is now period

```
a.b
a...c
..a..c
```